# fatal error:undefined function base_path() and path_to_theme in drupal-7

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a custom page and put it in the misc folder. When I call this page through ajax, it shows the following error:

> Fatal error: Undefined function `path_to_theme()` and `base_path()`

I have included the bootstrap.inc and the theme.inc files, but the error is still shown.

How can I use all the function and global variable on this page?

Comment: if you want to do a ajax call you can use hook_menu, is better

Comment: I can explain how to do with hook_menu

Answer (score 0):

As you put your page into misc folder, path_to_theme or overs functions hasn't been loaded yet.
I advice you to [create a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/361112) and do all your stuff here.

Answer (score 0):

```
//set the working directory to your Drupal root
chdir('/home/public_html/drupal/');

//require the bootstrap include
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';

//Load Drupal

drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
//(loads everything, but doesn't render anything)

//for example display a node
print '<pre>';
print_r(node_load(12));
print '</pre>';
```

[Official documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7)